# Embed same comment page in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a div id called common, the content that I would like to appear in this div is in the file share/_common.html.erb

What should I put in place of `<!-- content from _common.html.erb -->` so that the contents of share/_common.html.erb appears in the div?

```
<div id="common">
<!-- content from _common.html.erb -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your HTML comment with this:

```
<%= render :partial => "share/common" %>
```

or, if you're on Rails 2.3.x:

```
<%= render "share/common" %>
```